# Notify when a file descriptor is ready to read using callbacks?

Tags: c++, posix

Is there a simple way to do the following:

```
...
for each connection {
  create(ip)
}
...


int create(ip) {
  fd = connectToSocket(ip)
  addReadNotify(fd, readReady);
}

int readReady() {
  read(fd, ...)
  print read data
}
```

I'm looking for something with the ability of `addReadNotify` which takes a file descriptor and a callback function and whenever that fd is read-ready, calls the callback function.

I was hoping there is a library or something that can do this so I don't have to deal with threads myself.

Comment: Are you looking for a C or a C++ solution?

Comment: C++, I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some code doing the callbacks. Some kind of event loop, perhaps in a separate thread. Then you can use `select` to watch file descriptors. So what I'd do, I'd set up a thread to do the watching, and register stuff with its data structures.